# Why ${#}, ${##} are 1 and ${?}, ${??},and ${!} are 0 and ${-} is 569JNORXZghiklms

Tags: bash

I found the followings and want to know where I can find the manual:

```
❯ echo ${#}
1

❯ echo ${##}
1

❯ echo ${?}
0

❯ echo ${??}
0

❯ echo ${!}
0

❯ echo ${-}
569JNORXZghiklms

❯ echo ${--}
569JNORXZghiklms
```

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:bash], but the output you are showing seems to come from [tag:zsh]. Is `zsh` the shell you are actually using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In about two different places, at least in Bash's manual. These should be standard features, and similar in each shell even if the actual value of `${-}` here looks like it's from Zsh.

```
$ echo ${#}
1
$ echo ${?}
0
$ echo ${!}
0
$ echo ${-}
569JNORXZghiklms
```

These are the [special parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html) `#`, `?`, `!`, and `-`, expanded with the optional braces. Using `$#`, `$?`, `$!` or `$-` would be the same. There are some other special parameters with single non-letter non-digit characters as their "name" and in general, `${foo}` is the same as `$foo` but the braces are needed in a case like `${foo}bar`, since `$foobar` would be taken as `${foobar}`.

In particular,

- `$#` is the number of positional parameters or arguments to the script or current function. Try `fun() { echo $#; }; fun a b c;`.
- `$?` is the exit status of the last foreground command or pipeline (`ls -l /doesnotexist; echo $?`).
- `$!` the process id if the latest background job (`sleep 2 & ps uax |grep $!`), and
- `$-` the list of [`set` flags](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) in effect. (And some `setopt` flags in Zsh. Zsh also seems to give `$!` as `0` if there is no such job, Bash shows it as unset.)

```
$ echo ${##}
1
$ echo ${??}
0
$ echo ${--}
569JNORXZghiklms
```

These are the special parameters `#`, `?`, and `-`, but with additional [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) operations included. (I don't know what to call them, they're just part of parameter expansion.)

- `${#parameter}` is the length of the value of *parameter*, so when `$#` is `1` (or `0` etc.), `${##}` is `1`, and with `foo=abc`, `${#foo}` is `3`.

  (Somewhat related, `${parameter#word}` removes a prefix, it would be the value of *parameter* with the leading part matching *word* removed (e.g. `foo=abcdef; echo ${foo#??}` gives `cdef` since `?` matches any one character). The particular case of `${##}` could be interpreted as either taking the length, or removing an empty prefix, but the length expansion trumps here. `${parameter%word}` is the same but it removes a trailing part instead.)
- `${parameter?word}` is a "check if set" expansion, it gives the value of *parameter* if it's set, and otherwise throws an error with the text given by *word*. `$?` is always set, so the check doesn't do much, but try `unset foo; echo ${foo?unset value\!}`.
- `${parameter-word}` is a "default value" expansion, it takes the value of *parameter* if it is set, and otherwise *word*. `$-` is always set, so you get the value it has. But if `foo` is not set, `${foo-bar}` would be `bar`.

The last two and other similar ones have variants with a colon, `${parameter:?word}` and `${parameter:?word}`, which also trigger when *parameter* is set to the empty string. Bash's manual could be clearer here, it mentions the difference in the text, but doesn't list the forms without a colon. The [POSIX text has a nice table](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), though.

---

The fact that `#`, `?` and `-` have two different meanings here is just a coincidence, or a consequence of having a limited set of special characters and the shell using a rather terse syntax for the uses.